# Query Result for specific time interval

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table in MySQL db called price containing every day stock prices for multiple stocks. I want to display results for Fridays only so the date argument will be spaced by 7 days starting from "2012-11-23". The query (not working) is below

```
SELECT date, identifier, closingprice FROM price p
where date >="2012-11-23" and date = DATE_ADD(date, Interval 7 day)
```

Comment: Im reading you question again and to be clear, do you ONLY want to display FRIDAYS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have like range try this.

```
SELECT date, identifier, closingprice FROM price p
where date BETWEEN '2012-11-23' AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Using `BETWEEN` is useful when wanting to get between timespan.

You have to use `OR` if you dont want to have a timespan

```
SELECT date, identifier, closingprice FROM price p
where date >= '2012-11-23' OR date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Using `CURDATE()` gives the current date, without hours, seconds and minutes.

If you want to have only on Friday you can use function `DAYOFWEEK()`

```
SELECT date, identifier, closingprice FROM price p
where DAYOFWEEK(date) = 6
```

`6` is the integer value for Friday's

Comment: the last one works beautifully. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! God bless!

Comment: No problem happy to help! What you can do since you are new here is to set the answer YOU find best as a proper solution. You will for sure come back here as it is the mecka for developers :)

Comment: can't vote up (need at least 15 reputation) but accepted the answer as a proper solution

Comment: You dont have to vote it up :) But if a answer is to your satisfaction all you have to do is set it as accepted answers! Nice weekend!